# Input field doesn't clear on refresh in some browsers when using DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables-1.10

I have this little code in DataTables.net responsible for displaying Table.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Setup - add a text input to each header cell
            $('#DT-GRvWJTAH thead th').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
            });
            // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
            $('#DT-GRvWJTAH tfoot th').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
            });
            //  Table code
            var table = $('#DT-GRvWJTAH').DataTable({
                "dom": "Bfrtip",
                "buttons": [
                    "copyHtml5",
                    "excelHtml5",
                    "csvHtml5",
                    "pdfHtml5"
                ],
                "colReorder": true,
                "paging": true,
                "scrollCollapse": false,
                "pagingType": [
                    "full_numbers"
                ],
                "lengthMenu": [
                    [
                        15,
                        25,
                        50,
                        100
                    ],
                    -1,
                    [
                        15,
                        25,
                        50,
                        100
                    ],
                    "All"
                ],
                "ordering": true,
                "order": [

                ],
                "info": true,
                "procesing": true,
                "responsive": {
                    "details": true
                },
                "select": true,
                "searching": true,
                "stateSave": true
            });
            // Apply the search for header cells
            table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
                $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    table
                        .column(colIdx)
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                });

                $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('click', function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });
            });
            // Apply the search for footer cells
            table.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that.search(this.value).draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Full code here: https://codepen.io/przemyslawklys/pen/jRxLRy

It's a simple table with filtering enabled. The problem is when you filter on some column and press F5 to refresh the value from the input field is removed, but filtering stays on. If you go into that filter and press backspace it will start working again. The value is there, just invisible.

[image]

Now in my Chrome Canary, it doesn't have this issue, but I can see it in other browsers. I can even see it same Chrome when the code is hosted in code pen, so it's clearly there.

How can I address this? I see 2 options:

- make the filter show up properly so that the user is aware
- remove any filters on refresh

But how on my example I can accomplish this? I tried to play with it but had no real success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have

```
"stateSave": true
```

Your column filtering is saved along with all the other settings, most probably in localStorage, and when you hit F5 the previous state are restored. But you do not have any code that populate the inputs with the `saveState` search terms ..! Thus you get filtered data with empty input boxes.

You can get / set the `saveState` properties in multiple ways; a event handler will work with the above code but you should consider something more thought out:

```
$('#DT-GRvWJTAH').on('stateLoaded.dt', function(e, settings, data) {
  settings.aoPreSearchCols.forEach(function(col, index) {
    if (col.sSearch) setTimeout(function() {
      $('#DT-GRvWJTAH thead th:eq('+index+') input').val(col.sSearch)
    }, 50)
  })
})
```

Look at [**`stateSaveParams`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveParams) / [**`stateLoadParams`**](https://datatables.net/reference/event/stateLoadParams) where you can set / get the state for your column inputs.

Comment: This works! Thank you. Is there a way to distinguish input in tfoot and thead? When I added code for both and filtering is in both places on reload it fills both places, and not the one that actually had filter set up. While both have the  same role if you start changing things in thead, tfoot stays as is and therefore it looks bad. So either I have to have a way to keep Input fields keep in sync so when I type anything in thead it shows ups as filter in tfoot (if there is one) or somehow have different input names?

Comment: @MadBoy, you have two loops populating inputs to thead and tfoot; you could have one loop that populates both, and set a class by index on the inputs, i.e class="col3", by that you can set both thead and tfoot with $('input.col3').val(sSearch) and you can easier use the same handlers on both thead and tfoot inputs.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show this on the codepen of mine? I am a bit of noob when it comes to HTML/CSS and JS. I am doing this in in PowerShell (I generate the code and make it tick). My JS skills are close to 1% :(